# How to calculate near plane of camera in three.js with model bounding box

Tags: three.js

I am creating a viewer using three.js and found that setting camera near and far plane to fixed values is causing flickering for some 3d models.

I see that this is due to the fact that GPU is running out of precision for model having bounding box length around 4000-5000.

Near plane is currently set to 0.1 and far to 20000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move up your near plane to get more resolution. Maybe 1.0...

Another option to be aware of is logarithmic depth buffer:
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_camera_logarithmicdepthbuffer.html

You can get the bounding box of the mesh via its geometry... geometry.boundingBox and geometry.boundingSphere .. sometimes you need to recalculate them using mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox and computeBoundingSphere...

To get the bounding box in camera space is a bit tricky.. I don't know of a super optimal one-liner to do it, but someone else may weigh in...

a brute force way would be to transform the mesh vertices to screen space..

Maybe something like:

```
var gclone = mesh.geometry.clone();
for(var i=0;i<geometry.vertices.length;i++)
  gclone.vertices[i].applyMatrix4(mesh.matrixWorld).project(camera)
gclone.computeBoundingBox()

var zExtent = gclone.boundingBox.max.z-gclone.boundingBox.min.z
```

Comment: I am able to calculate the bounding box already. My problem is that my models vary from 1.22 to 4000 in bounding box length. 1.0 fails for smaller ones, where as the 0.1 fails for the bigger.

Even logarithmic z-buffer fails for smaller ones

Comment: There are limits to numeric precision. Can you describe what you are building in a little more detail? There may be other ways to approach it? Why do you have such large differences in size for your geometries?

Comment: I used the logarithmic depth buffer and it worked. The parts I use vary from small cicuit board parts to large buildings, hence it varies. But none of them are at micrometers (at which logarithmic depth buffer fails) and hence the solution works for me.

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help :)